# SQL, how to group rows based on field values

Tags: sql, group-by, combinations

i have question about query result group. The image is a example. it is cable list. Each cable come with two attributes, 'From' location and 'To' location. if we'd like to group the cable list by location, it becomes tricky.

when we group the data by two locations, the results will land into two groups.

- 'A->B',
- 'B->A'

But in reality, it makes more sense to combine these two groups into one, 'From<->', or saying cable list between two locations.

Think of add one more filed to mark cables between two locations. But didn't come up with any idea.

thank you for sharing your thoughts.

regards,
Roland

SQL, group

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT7pu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the least and the greatest of the 2 columns.
Use your database's functions to do this.
The SQL standard is a `CASE` expression like:

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN A < B THEN A ELSE B END,
         CASE WHEN A < B THEN B ELSE A END
```

Or maybe you can use a function like `IF()` or `IIF()`:

```
GROUP BY IF(A < B, A, B),
         IF(A < B, B, A)
```

or functions like `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`:

```
GROUP BY LEAST(A, B),
         GREATEST(A, B)
```

Comment: Hi Forpas, it is such a great help. i am sorry for the bad writing. i was afraid if people could understand what i was saying. you rock. it is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: again, thank you so much Forpas, also the group as well.

Comment: absolutely, would you show me where the checkmark is? i didn't find it on this page.